# Nimble parallel and series mix works in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nimble

This sample of code from node.js in action book:

```
var flow = require('nimble');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function downloadNodeVersion(version, destination, callback) {
  var url = 'http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v' + version + '.tar.gz';
  var filepath = destination + '/' + version + '.tgz';
  exec('curl ' + url + ' >' + filepath, callback);
}

flow.series([
  function (callback) {
    flow.parallel([
      function (callback) {
        console.log('Downloading Node v0.4.6...');
        downloadNodeVersion('0.4.6', '/tmp', callback);
      },
      function (callback) {
        console.log('Downloading Node v0.4.7...');
        downloadNodeVersion('0.4.7', '/tmp', callback);
      }
    ], callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    console.log('Creating archive of downloaded files...');
    exec(
      'tar cvf node_distros.tar /tmp/0.4.6.tgz /tmp/0.4.7.tgz',
      function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('All done!');
        callback();
      }
    );
  }
]);
```

but second function(callback) in flow.series does not executed i.e. final .tar archive does not created. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's in an exec() block - so the context is lost.